# CNAME for Azure Traffic Manager with Azure Functions (error: Custom domain has not been configured inside Azure)

Tags: azure-traffic-manager, azure-dns

I have multiple Azure Functions in different regions and I use a Traffic Manager to access the closest endpoint in the region. Everything works as expected.

But I want a custom domain (e.g. api.mydomain.com). I created a CNAME in my CloudFlare DNS that points to my Traffic Manager endpoint. When I use the CNAME in my browser, I see this error:
`Custom domain has not been configured inside Azure.`

[image]

Is there any of fixing this issue? It seems like Azure doesn't like other DNS services.
I want a FREE solution.

Answer (score 0):

To configure a custom domain for Azure Functions with Traffic Manager, you need to create a CNAME record that points to the Traffic Manager endpoint. However, it seems that you are encountering an error that says "Custom domain has not been configured inside Azure". This error occurs when the custom domain has not been added to the Azure Function app. To fix this issue, you need to add the custom domain to the Azure Function app by following these steps:

1. In the Azure portal, navigate to your Function app and select "Custom domains" under "Settings".
2. Click on "+ Add custom domain" and enter your custom domain name (e.g. api.mydomain.com).
3. Click on "Validate" to verify that the custom domain has been configured correctly.
4. Once the custom domain has been validated, click on "Add custom domain" to add it to the Function app.
   [image]

After adding the custom domain to the Function app, you should be able to access it using the CNAME record that points to the Traffic Manager endpoint.

References:

- [Use Azure DNS to provide custom domain settings for an Azure service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/dns/dns-custom-domain#azure-function-app)
- [Configure a custom domain name in Azure App Service with Traffic Manager integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-domain-traffic-manager#configure-a-custom-domain-name-in-azure-app-service-with-traffic-manager-integration)

Comment: I have multiple Azure Functions Apps? What should I do? Add the same CNAME for all of them, and then use the same CNAME for the traffic manager? I can't set multiple CNAMES for the same HOST value in my DNS settings. How should I proceed?

Comment: How many function apps you have in total? all in same region? You cannot add the same custom domain to multiple apps in the same region, but it should be possible with apps in different regions. If you have multiple Azure Functions Apps and want to use the same custom domain with Traffic Manager, you can add the same CNAME for all of them and then use the same CNAME for the Traffic Manager. However, you cannot set multiple CNAMEs for the same HOST value in your DNS settings.

Comment: Refer to [Running same custom domain in different Azure App Services in same region](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/202552/running-same-custom-domain-in-different-azure-app) and [Error 404](https://blogs.blackmarble.co.uk/sspencer/setting-custom-domain-for-traffic-manager-and-azure-websites/)

Comment: Another option is using TXT record, when you configure a TXT record instead of CNAME record App service treats it as domain migration and allows the validation to succeed
Read the section under [Configure a custom domain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-web-tutorial-custom-domain?tabs=root,azurecli#3-validate-and-complete) and [Configuring DNS->Custom Domain reccomended](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configure-web-app?tabs=customdomain,azure-portal#configuring-dns)

Comment: I have multiple azure function apps across multiple regions (US, EU, etc).

Comment: You can go ahead and create multiple CNAMES only. "I can't set multiple CNAMES for the same HOST value in my DNS settings." it's possible to do so. First verify with AppService 1 and remove the DNS records, then do for AppService2 and go on.